# Websphere Application Server 7.0 - Activation Specification - Retry Connection to Remote Websphere MQ

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

We are currently using an Activation Specification on WAS 7.0 to listen to the WMQ Queues.
At times WMQ Queue Manager goes down and we need to retry to connect to the WMQ from WAS Activation Specification. Is it possible?

If we use Listener Port in WAS there is "Maximum Retry" property available to retry the connection. But unable to find a property which helps in Retry for Activation Specification.

Kindly help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following properties to configure Activation Specifications retry policy.

```
reconnectionRetryCount
The maximum number of the attempts that are made by the resource adapter to reconnect to a WebSphere MQ queue manager if a connection fails.
The default value is 5.
```

and

```
reconnectionRetryInterval
The time, in milliseconds, that the resource adapter waits before it makes another attempt to reconnect to a WebSphere MQ queue manager.
The default value is 300000 ms.
```

You need to [configure this as Custom Properties.](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/tmm_customproperties_ra.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Will definitely try this and provide the update.

Comment: Another question related to Custom Properties. The Queue Manager is with another team hence it is not possible to bring it down in lower environment to test the properties - reconnectionRetryCount and reconnectionRetryInterval.

Is there any other way to see if these properties are working?

Comment: @Marcos do you know how to configure the "reconnectionRetryInterval" via the WAS console?

Comment: @Dion_E - Actually it's a step by step showed in the link I used to answer the question :) The link is for WebSphere v7 but v8.x should be the same.  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/tmm_customproperties_ra.html

Comment: @MarcosMaia that is so strange, I use the console of WebSphere V7 and cannot locate the property "Reconnection retry count". Could you please add a screenshot on the answer?

Comment: I use V7.0.0.19 specifically - I am not sure if these features are supported for my version.

Answer (score 0):

Dio might have figured it out by now how to find the property :), the following info is for any new users that are facing this :

To configure WMQ RA settings, go to
Resources → Resource Adapters, select a scope to configure, and in the Preferences, select“Show built-in resources”, and Apply.

- Select the “WebSphere MQ Resource Adapter”
- Select custom properties, and modify the “reconnectionRetryCount” and “reconnectionRetryInterval” properties